# Toggle hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I'm trying to re create a portfolio section similar to the one on this site http://www.iamjamesmcgill.com/, when you click on an image it slides open a hidden div and displays the content within. When you have viewed the content you click the x to close and it slides back up. I have played with the toggle function on jsfiddle ( can provide link if needed ) but cant seem to replicate the above code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: OK. So lets have the fiddle so we can play to :-)

Comment: Its a work in progress http://jsfiddle.net/La2m53ch/1/ - ideally getting it as close to the link above - but I'm coming up short!

Answer (score 0):

Hope its right

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".content").hide();
    //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
    jQuery(".portfolio-item").click(function () {
        jQuery(".content").slideToggle(100);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/La2m53ch/2/

Comment: This seems to work, but when I click on one it opens and when i click on another it opens as well, I was hoping that when one was clicked it  could close an already open div - you can see here whats happening http://jsfiddle.net/La2m53ch/5/

Answer (score 0):

You are only using [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) in your function. jQuery website describes:

> *Get the immediately following **sibling** of each element in the set of
>   matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next
>   sibling only if it matches that selector.*

Looking at your hierarchy, you'll notice that `.content` isn't a sibling. Therefor, you'll first need to go up in your hierarchy, and then look for `.content`. You can accomplish that by using [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).

(Side note: the [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) function will only go up one level in the hierarchy, therefor we use `parents()` in your function.)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".content").hide();
    //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
    jQuery(".portfolio-item").click(function () {
        jQuery(this).parents().next(".content").slideToggle(100);
    });
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/La2m53ch/3/).

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/La2m53ch/1/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".content").hide();
    //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
    jQuery(".portfolio-item").click(function (e) {
    $(this).parent().find(".content").slideToggle(100);
    });
});
```

Check the fiddle you also need to change your markup.

Comment: I'm not defensive. jQuery is not past technology. It's a library in use by trillions of websites. CSS3 is still in it's infancy.

Comment: And you are producing your opinion as a fact here. I would remove that as it is not the Stackoverflow way to do things. Also: the fiddle you link to doesn't seem to do anything for me (on firefox at least).